# runtime exception after upgrade to Xcode4.5 iOS6 Base SDK

Tags: ios6, xcode4.5

I recently upgraded my codebase to use iOS6 Base SDK - I am using XCode 4.5. I only had to change the dylibxml2.2.3.7 to dylibxml2.2. It works fine on the 6.0 simulator. I am using libs like GoogleAnalytics, Three20.

But when i run the code on iOS 5 (iPhone4), it crashes at launch with this following error:

I can't tell where it is exactly crashing because all I see is the machine codes when it crashes

**dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _objc_setProperty_nonatomic**

> Referenced from: /Users//Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications//
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I meet the same error too when building my own lib and run it in my sample code. After reading the build log carefully, I figure out the reason now.

I set my deployment target to iOS 3.0, but the latest Xcode only support iOS 4.3 and later. So the compiler automatically set the deployment target to iOS 6.0, which generates error whenever the project is running under iOS 6.0. I fixed it by setting the deployment target to iOS 4.3 in my lib project.

Comment: Awesome! Worked for me - I totally overlooked that part - Its unbeleivable how crazy things can get when you upgrade to new iOS and new xCode - Thanks a ton !

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in changng SDK deployment target alone. I just created a tab based application. Didn't do any change in any file. Running fine on ios 6 simulator but if I change
deployment target to 5 and run on ios 5 simulator which is creating exception(signal SIGABRT). Xcode version 4.5 and default deployment target SDK 6.0.

Comment: +1 for iPhoney answer. Inaddition to that, if you are using xib or storyboard, make sure to uncheck "useautolayout" in interface builder, when you are running on ios5. Bydefault this option is checked for ios6 sdk target.

Answer (score 0):

Or it could be that you are using a library that was compiled with a higher base SDK than your project base SDK.