# iPhone 5.1 App using OpenCV crashes due to "nonatomic" not found

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, opencv, ios6

I'm developing an iOS App which targets iOS 5.1+. I'm using XCode 4.5 on Mac OS X 10.8 and I do own an iPhone 4 with iOS 5.1.1. The app needs OpenCV, which I have successfully built from sources according to a [tutorial in the OpenCV-Documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/ios_install/ios_install.html).

Here is what happens:

When I start up the application I get an exception:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _objc_setProperty_nonatomic
```

The error does not occur with iOS 6, but with iOS 5.1 in both the simulator and on a real device.

What is that? Is it related to OpenCV? Does it have to do something with incompatibilities between iOS / the iPhone / XCode??

***EDIT:*** My development target is set to 5.1. The Base SDK is 6.0. I copied an SDK für 4.3 (which is the lowest version that XCode 4.5 will support) from another Mac and set development target as well as the base SDK to 4.3. Did not work either (it did not even build then).

I did not an update, the project has been started from scratch using XCode 4.5 initially.

Meanwhile I also found a tip to use gnulibc++ instead of libc++, but that also resulted in that the project did not build at all.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573685/runtime-exception-after-upgrade-to-xcode4-5-ios6-base-sdk ?

Comment: I have seen exactly that question but the workaround did not work for me. Also I did not upgrade or anything, I started the project from scratch on a clean new install of XCode 4.5

Comment: So your deployment target is set to iOS 5?

Comment: Did you try base sdk iOS 5?

Comment: Base SDK iOS 5 is not available in XCode 4.5 and I do not have another XCode version. 4.3 was pure luck since I have an older XCode on my MacBook.

Comment: Base SDK is available, go to your build settings, it's the 3rd item down

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20424/discussion-between-scravy-and-combinatorial)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I built a test project and found the same issue. OpenCV is being built with a deployment target of ios6, this is a known issue, and a fix is pending review, see https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/pull/70

Comment: I pulled the patched repositories and built it, which works for me now.